# Mongo error 301 occurs when doing write operations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typeorm, aws-documentdb

When doing write operations(save, delete), Mongo Error occurs on my Nodejs server. Error code is 301.

I'm using TypeORM v0.2.29 and mongodb v3.6.3 right now. The database is AWS DocumentDB.

This is simplified server code:

```js
import { createConnections } from 'typeorm';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import ObjectID from 'bson-objectid';

const [mongodb, ...] = await createConnections([
  {
    url: 'mongodb://<username>:<password>@docdb~~.amazonaws.com/<database>?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred',
    ssl: true,
    sslValidate: true,
    sslCA: [readFileSync('/path/to/ssl/ca')],
  },
  {...}
]);

const repository = mongodb.getMongoRepository(SomeEntity);

const entity = new SomeEntity();
entity.id = ObjectID.generate();
entity.someValue = someValue;

await repository.findOne(1); //works fine
const result = await repository.save([entity]); //MongoError occurs
```

Edit: Turns out id is defined before the entity is persisted. Is that could be a problem?

Edit 2: I tried on development enviornment(it took quite amount of time to set up. sorry for give you the information late), and I got `Retryable writes not supported` error. This is full error message:
[image: Mongo error]

However, no matter if I put `retryWrites=false` option on query string, it gives the same error.

Comment: Could you please post a full error message?

Comment: `{"ok":0,"code":301,"operationTime":"6914097073893670913","name":"MongoError"}` This is it.

Comment: Can you show me the results for repository.findById? How did you check the normal operation? When checking the code, it seems that `TypeORM v0.2.29` does not have a `findById` function.

Comment: Sorry, it's `findOne`. I defined custom data accessor, and forgot about that.

Comment: It seems that you should check the write permissions policies of the aws document db. There is no problem in code.

Comment: I double checked and there's no problem with my permissions.
`roles: [{"db": "<database>", "role": "readWrite"}]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226864/discussion-between--and-myeongkil-kim).